# Trouble Returning CGPoint

Tags: objective-c, cgpoint

I got this method:

```
-(CGPoint) getPointOnaLine: (CGPoint) p1: (CGPoint) p2: (int) dt {
    CGPoint tempPoint;
    float myY = p1.y;
    float len = getLineLength( p1, p2 );
    float res = 1000;
    // do not bother with calculation with small widths
    if ( dt == 0 )
        return p1;
    if ( len < (2 / res ) ) 
        return p2;
    float increm = len / res;
    //  int min = 2;

    float dY = p2.y - p1.y;
    float dx = p2.x - p1.x;

    if ( dx != 0 ) {          // slope is infinite
        float slope = dY / dx;

        float b = p1.y - slope * p1.x;

        if ( p1.x < p2.x ) {
            for ( float i= p1.x; i<=p2.x; i=i+increm ) {
                myY = (slope * i + b);
                tempPoint = ccp(i,myY);
                len = getLineLength( p1,  tempPoint);
                if ( len >= dt)
                    return tempPoint;
            }
        } else if ( p1.x > p2.x )
            for ( float i= p2.x; i<=p1.x; i=i+increm) {
                myY = (slope * i + b);
                tempPoint = ccp(i,myY);
                len = getLineLength( p2, tempPoint);
                if ( len >= dt )
                    return tempPoint;
            }
    } else {
        return p2;
    }
    return p1;
}
```

I use it in another method:

```
CGPoint b1, b2, pt;
b1 = getPointOnaLine(originalPoint, bezierPoint, (int)t*stepLine1);
b2 = getPointOnaLine(bezierPoint, targetPoint, (int)t*stepLine2);
bLen = getLineLength(b1,b2);
stepLine3 = bLen / frames;
pt =  getPointOnaLine(b1,b2,(int)self.tCGPoint b1, b2, pt;
```

The compiler keep telling me "Incompatable types in assignment" where I declare b1, b2, and pt.  The interface is:

```
-(CGPoint) getPointOnaLine: (CGPoint) p1: (CGPoint) pt2: (int) dt;
```

If I remove the assignment it just gives me an Implicit declaration warning.  I'm really confused about why this won't compile.

Chris

Answer (score 2):

You've defined a method (though with oddly unnamed parameters) but you're calling it as a function.

Try:

```
b1 = [self getPointOnaLine:originalPoint :bezierPoint :(int)t*stepLine1];
```

(Better still, declare it with parameter names to make reading easier for your future self.)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling objective-c messages in the c-function style, instead use it as

```
b1 = [self getPointOnaLine:originalPoint :bezierPoint  :(int)t*stepLine1];
b2 = [self getPointOnaLine:bezierPoint :targetPoint :(int)t*stepLine2];
```

if b1 and b2 are initialized in the same class, otherwise self is to be replaced by the object that has `getPointOnaLine:bezierPoint` method defined.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I knew it was some thing simpe.  I'm a JAVA guy.

Comment: Oh, you'll like the syntax then :)